# adding values of php array together in multidemsional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array in php that is like this

```
     Array
       (
           [0] => Array
               (
                   [user] => 1
               )           
       )
       Array
       (
           [0] => Array
               (
                   [vote] => 3.0
               )

           [1] => Array
               (
                   [vote] => 5.0
               )           
       )
```

I need to add together the values of vote ( 3.0 + 5.0 = 8) in the array

what is the best way to do this in php

Comment: Do you want to add only values of the array having "vote" as a key?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this:

```
$sum = $the_second_array[0];
for($i=1; $i<count($the_second_array); $i++){
  $sum += $the_second_array[$i];
}
```

Add first index value into temporary, then looping from second index of array for sum the next value.

Answer (score 1):

To add the values of vote you can do as follows:

```
array_sum(array_column($array[1], 'vote'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
//assuming $array is your array...
$score = 0;
foreach($array[1] as $element)
{
    foreach($element as $key=>$val)
    {
        if('vote'==$key)
        {
             $score+=$val;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo here:](https://eval.in/669158)

```
<?php $arrays = array(array(array('user' => 1)), array(array('vote' => 3.0), array( 'vote' => 5.0)));
var_dump(array_map(function($array){return array_sum(array_map(function($value){return $value['vote'] ? $value['vote'] : 0;}, $array));}, $arrays));
```